# Touch Events ImageView + GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener, touch-event, glsurfaceview

I was wondering whether it was possible to have a ImageView over a GLSurfaceView and get the respective touch events of both. My problem is that I want to know when the ImageView is pressed (thus I would use a OnTouchListener). But still, I want to be able to get the touchEvents of my GLSurfaceView.

What I have tried is to remove the implementation of onTouchEvent from my GLSurfaceView and make the class implement OnTouchListener and implement onTouchsuch as:

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.ImageView ;){
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             //Do something 
             break ;
        //....
    }
}
else{
    //Process GLSurfaceView touch events
 }
}
```

The problem when I do that is that I cannot combine touching my imageView and touching my GLSurfaceView which is what I actually want to achieve. I have therefore tried to add a check on the number of fingers, but still cannot get it to work as only one finger is detected when I touch both the ImageView and the GLSurfaceView.
Now, it's difficult to explain but when I put one finger over the imageView and one finger somewhere else on my GLSurfaceView, somehow my piece of code in the else part is in called with the finger position over the ImageView, and not the other finger.

One use case example would be:Imagine I'm using my two hands while holding the tablet. If I'm pressing this ImageView with my thumb on the left hand, I want finger movements from my right thumb on the screen to perform rotations instead of translations or something like that.

So, I was wondering what was wrong with my implementation so far. Maybe I'm not considering the problem correctly. In which case I'd be happy to know what's wrong and how to implement this kind of things correctly.

Thanks in advance,

---

Edit:
Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id= "@+id/linearlayout1" >

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:id= "@+id/relativeLayout" >


        <com.kitware.VolumeRender.VolumeRenderView
            android:id="@+id/glSurfaceViewID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.23" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/i3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tmp" />

</RelativeLayout>        

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/myspinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" /> 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id= "@+id/linearlayout2" >
// And so on, the end of the file is irrelevant I suppose
```

Comment: are the view bounds of both these views same? Also which is on top?

Comment: @Bhargav did not quite get your first question. The ImageView is on top. Coming edit to add my activity_main.xml content

Comment: meaning is the ImageView's completely covering over the surface view? IF so then your surfaceView can never gain focus

Comment: @Bhargav, So it's actually not completely covering my GLSurfaceView. You can see the details in my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
imageView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        } else {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
    }
});
```

And same with your surfaceView too

Comment: Not sure this is going to work. I want to be able to touch both my ImageView and the GLSurfaceView at the same time, not having something binary either the imageView or the GLSurfaceView, which is what I already have. How is your code going to change this? I am not sure I understand the purpose of that piece of code

Comment: yes you will be able to touch both of them as long as both of them are focusable, as you can see from the code, when hasFocus is false, false is passed to `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)`

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't change the fact that concurrent touch events do not work properly. The problem is that my chunk of code in the GLSurfaceView ProccesTouchEvent is called with the finger position over the imageView

Comment: then when the imagview has focus nake the surface clickae false

Comment: But I don't want it to be not clickable. Look at the use case I gave in my question for more information. Kinda hard to explain ^^

Comment: yes make it clickable again when imageview loses focus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105122/discussion-between-lbes-and-bhargav).